# How can i write single jquery function for multiple series of id's for their series of dependent id's?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I wrote below code using while loop printed like below

```
<p>

<input id="txtBox<?php echo $a; ?>" type="text" value="1" style="display:none;" />

<span id="txtBoxValue<?php echo $a; ?>">1</span>

</p>
```

when I click or select on the span I need convert it to the text field and after when deselect it will return to span text again

for this task, I wrote multiple jquery functions but I need it to be a single function is it possible?

thankyou in advance

```
<script> 
    $(function() {

    $('#txtBoxValue1').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide(); 
        $('#txtBox1').show(); 
    });

    $('#txtBox1').on('blur', function() {
        var that = $(this);
        $('#txtBoxValue1').text(that.val()).show(); 
        that.hide(); 
    });


    $('#txtBoxValue2').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide(); 
        $('#txtBox2').show(); 
    });

    $('#txtBox2').on('blur', function() {
        var that = $(this);
        $('#txtBoxValue2').text(that.val()).show(); 
        that.hide(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it dynamic. use `class="textboxevent" data-id="<?php echo $a; ?>"`

```html
<p>
  <input class="textboxevent" id="txtBox<?php echo $a; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $a; ?>" type="text" value="1" style="display:none;" />    
  <span class="txtBoxValue<?php echo $a; ?>">1</span>
</p>
```

```js
$(function() {    
  $('.textboxevent').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    $('#txtBox' + id).show(); 
  });

  $('.textboxevent').on('blur', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#txtBoxValue' + id).text(that.val()).show(); 
    that.hide(); 
  });       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Incremental `id` attributes are an anti-pattern, mostly because they lead to needlessly verbose JS logic.

A better solution is to use common classes on element with the same behaviour and then use DOM traversal to relate the elements to those around them. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.txtBoxValue').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide().prev('input.txtBox').show();
  });

  $('.txtBox').on('blur', function() {
    var $that = $(this).hide();
    $that.next('.txtBoxValue').text($that.val()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.txtBox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input class="txtBox" type="text" value="1" />
  <span class="txtBoxValue">1</span>
</p>
<p>
  <input class="txtBox" type="text" value="2" />
  <span class="txtBoxValue">2</span>
</p>
<p>
  <input class="txtBox" type="text" value="3" />
  <span class="txtBoxValue">3</span>
</p>
```